# How to return the largest number from a series of integers the user entered without using arrays?

Tags: java, methods, do-while

I learned about creating my own methods earlier today, and was tasked by our instructor to create a Java program that would prompt the user to enter the number of numbers (a counter, if you will) he would like to input, and the numbers themselves (limited by the said counter that was set). The console would then display the largest number among all the numbers that were entered. I would like to know if this is possible to do without the use of arrays (disregarding the level of difficulty, of course; I just want to be able to appreciate arrays more by learning this first).

Here's the code I came up with so far, but it won't run so I'm pretty sure it's wrong and really far-off from the right answer:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Largest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);

    int ctr=0;
    int list=0;
    double nums=0;


    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to enter?");
    ctr=input.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Enter the " + ctr + " numbers to determine which is the largest: ");

    do
    {
      nums=input.nextDouble();
      list++;
    } while (list!=ctr);

    System.out.println("The largest among the " + ctr + " numbers is " + largest(nums));
    }

    public static double largest (double nums) 

    {
        double maxValue = Double.MIN_VALUE;

            if (nums > maxValue){
                maxValue = nums;
                }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

At the moment, I am running out of ideas. Please understand that I am extremely new to Java and all I know about it is from stuff I've read online. I can't find much on the internet regarding this specific program so any sort of help will be appreciated!

Basically, this is what I want the console to look like during output:

```
How many numbers would you like to enter?
5
Enter the 5 numbers to determine which one is the largest: 
4
8
2
10
5
The largest among the 5 numbers is 10.
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I've updated the code above and everything works perfectly except for the fact that the number that is displayed is **always** the last number entered, not necessarily the largest number in the series. And before anyone asks, I wanted to try calling one of the methods I created in this program, so as much as possible, if this code could be fixed without having to get rid of `public static double largest (double nums)`, that would be awesome.

Comment: If you want to achieve the exact output you posted, you need to store the numbers somewhere to be printed later. Therefore you need an array. Also you have quite a few `{` and `}` in the wrong places.

Comment: @Danny Ah yes, that's probably why it didn't run. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting the numbers one by one, you only need to store the maximum number you have so far. No arrays needed.

Instead of adding your numbers to list in your do loop, simply compare the new number to a maxValue.

1. Initialise maxValue to the first number that is input.
2. In the do loop compare all subsequent numbers to maxValue and replace maxValue if the new number is larger

Comment: How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use arrays:

1. `largest` = -∞
2. Read input `x`
3. If `x > largest` set `largest = x`
4. Go to 2

Translate this to Java and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
double largest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
do
{
  nums=input.nextDouble();
  if (nums > largest)
    largest = nums;
  list++;
} while (list!=ctr);
```

Comment: Are you sure that `list=list+nums;` is what you meant to type?